# XNA: get screen's width and height

Tags: xna, fullscreen

how do i get the width and height of the entire screen in XNA?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

This seems to be it (just googled for "xna screen width height" myself):

```
GraphicsAdapter.DefaultAdapter.CurrentDisplayMode.Height
GraphicsAdapter.DefaultAdapter.CurrentDisplayMode.Width
```

Answer (score 81):

Empirically I've found that in XNA 4.0 I need to use

```
GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width
GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height
```

when running windowed mode, as I find

```
GraphicsDevice.DisplayMode.Width
GraphicsDevice.DisplayMode.Height
```

gives me the resolution of the entire screen.

Hopefully this helps someone else out.

Comment: That was actually what i was asking for; window width/height is a different thing.

Answer (score 3):

GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Bounds - this returns Rectangle2D and it has parameters Width and Height.