# XNA - Get Current Screen Resolution

Tags: c#, xna, screen, desktop, resolution

Is it possible to get the current desktop screen resolution?

I have a few minor settings in my XNA game one of which is screen resolution. What I want to do is blank out a screen resolution option if it is larger than the current desktop resolution supports.

Comment: possible duplicate of [XNA: get screen's width and height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377524/xna-get-screens-width-and-height)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`GraphicsAdapter.DefaultAdapter.CurrentDisplayMode.Width` and `.Height` will give you the device's current resolution.

`Game.GraphicsDevice.Viewport` has height and width variables you can query, that will give you the resolution of your viewport. The viewport is usually the size of the window, but that's not guaranteed.

`Window.ClientBounds.Width` and `.Height` will give you the resolution of your game window.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I found the answer to be: 
GraphicsAdapter.DefaultAdapter.CurrentDisplayMode.Width
GraphicsAdapter.DefaultAdapter.CurrentDisplayMode.Height

Comment: Ah yes, you're right. Viewport gives you the resolution of your game window, which can be smaller than the entire desktop if you're in windowed mode on a PC, whereas CurrentDisplayMode gives you the desktop resolution. I will edit my answer to include those details for future readings.

Comment: Viewport can be changed to have a size smaller than the window (ex. splitscreen). I would stick with Window.ClientBounds.Width/Height.

Comment: Thanks YellPike, I've added that information to the answer.

Answer (score 9):

`GraphicsAdapter.SupportedDisplayModes` will return a collection of all of the supported aspect ratios. You can then show all of the ratios that are in this collection.

Comment: Nevermind, looks like I misread the question. I'll leave it here for anyone else who may need it.