# How can i get the width and height of the screen in xna?

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

So in my 2d tower defense game I need to get the resolution of the screen for use in my scaling matrix. However I can't find a way that works. I've tried:

```
_graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width
```

and

```
GraphicsAdapter.DefaultAdapter.CurrentDisplayMode.Width

//It always crashes the game
_graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth
//Also crashes
```

THis is my exact code

```
screenscalex = (float) *whatever i put here* / 1366f;
```

Thank you!

Comment: "*However I can't find a way that works.*" Which ways have you tried? [XNA: get screen's width and height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377524/xna-get-screens-width-and-height)?

Comment: have you tried `graphics.PresentationParameters.PreferredBackBufferWidth`? (and height)

Comment: Here i put on the code that i've tried

Comment: What do you mean by "crash"?

Comment: It goes back to the start screen and the game stops debugging

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are doing these checks after initialize is called. the graphics device must be initialized before checking these items.